# How to de-tide a daily averaged sea level data?

Tags: oceanography, sea-level, tides, tide-station

Coud you help me to resolve this situation? : I have a raw daily averaged sea level time series, as you know when we perform a harmonic analysis (e.g. using T_Tide from MATLAB) we need to put our data in hourly measurements. For example, if you analyze a data series sampled every minute, in T_Tide you must put: 'interval', 1/60.  But in my case I don´t know how to do such analysis since my data are in daily measurements. Any suggestion?
Thank you so much.